# How do i get data from firebase and display in html?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This my code so far (ive gone through several iterations and nothing works)
Im trying to get the patients email and display it on my html web page.

Ideally im trying to get the data to display in a html form but im just using alert for now to get it showing.

```html
<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAJzJubsXxt0LaXArXTqReJPc29EEibg9w",
    authDomain: "medapp-f2621.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://medapp-f2621.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "medapp-f2621",
    storageBucket: "medapp-f2621.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "655222508631",
    appId: "1:655222508631:web:98c905fa1905a1f22f6712",
    measurementId: "G-927SW3SCE0"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();



  var patientsRef = firebase.database().ref("patients");

  patientsRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  var childData = childSnapshot.val();
  var email=childData.email;
  window.alert(email);
 });
});
</script>
```

Here is the database 
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxO7q.png)

Comment: Can you clarify which part doesn't work? Is it getting the data, or putting it on the web page? Does `window.alert(email);` correctly alert the email?

Comment: I think both, i tried console.log(email) and it says "firebase.database is undefined" at  var patientsRef = firebase.database().ref("patients");

Comment: So im not even sure if its even connected. If it will output the email then it should be able to put in a table without issue.

Comment: Have you added the Firebase SDKs? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize

Comment: Yeah added that and still nothing

Comment: I have barely any experience with firebase as you can probably tell so please forgive me haha

Comment: If it says `firebase.database() is not a function`, then you are probably missing one of the libraries. Firebase is split up into several libraries. Make sure you've added all the files required by the SDK. Try adding `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-database.js"></script>` to your web page.